# How To Improve Browser Detection with Request.Context.Browser Object?

Tags: .net, browser

I'm using an HTTP handler in .NET 2.0 and need to detect browser and version. How do I implement [Ocean's Browsercaps](http://owenbrady.net/browsercaps/) in .NET 2.0?

Answer (score 1):

You could just email Owen Brady the maintainer of the software package in question. He does have a version of the software that runs independent of Microsoft's Browsercaps processor. [2.0 version](http://owenbrady.net/projects/Ocean2.Web.HttpCapabilities.zip)